# PHP Multi Statement Exec in Background

Tags: php, linux, command-line

I have a PHP script that needs to run some background command line calls to create some files in the background. I do not want the user to have to wait until the command line stuff is done before the page loads. I have tried using the answers from other threads on SO and it is not working for me.

Here is what I have tried via exec() and shell_exec() to get it to run in the background:

```
'{ [multiple commands here] }  &> /dev/null &;
```

If it is helpful, this is the server info:

```
uname -or
2.6.39-400.17.1.el6uek.x86_64 GNU/Linux

lsb_release -irc
Distributor ID: OracleServer
Release:    6.4
Codename:   n/a
```

Comment: have you tried `exec()`?

Comment: Yes, I've used both exec() and shell_exec() to run the commands, but they wait until the shell is done before returning.

Comment: `'{ [multiple commands here] }  &> /dev/null &;` doesn't really make any sense

Comment: whats the *exact* code you tried?

Comment: PHP has native calls that can create files.  You might wish to try using them.

Comment: I first create a directory (if not exists) and write a few files to it. then I run the following { cd [Directory 1]; git pull [git repository] --rebase; cd [Directory 2]; git add [Directory 2]; cd [Directory 1]; git commit -m "message"; git push [repository address] master; } &> /dev/null &;

Comment: to Kkinsey: I am using PHP's native file creation functions to create the files. I use the command line to push them to a Git repository

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this example will help you out. Replace the commands with your commands.

```
<?php
shell_exec("{ sleep 10; touch /tmp/asdf; } > /dev/null 2>&1 &");
```

Comment: Hi Chris, is your answer essentially changing the stderr to stdout (and adding the ampersand make it a background process) so I can see what's happening behind the scenes? If so, I know I'm not getting errors with the command line stuff. It's working, it just takes too long and I need to return back to the user while it's processing. The ampersand doesnt seem to have an effect on making it a background process or not. which is why I included the server information in case it needs a variation of the ampersand

Comment: It redirects stdout and stderr to /dev/null and backgrounds the process. Try running my code verbatim and you should find that the page finishes loading immediately and after 10 seconds the file `/tmp/asdf` is created. I don't see why anything other than `&` would be required unless you are using a particularly weird shell.